# ng-repeat not working in ui-popover-html

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

When ng-repeat is used in ui-popover-html, getting error - 
**Token 'item' is an unexpected token** . 
Code is given below:

```
<div uib-popover-html="'<span ng-repeat='item in ${this.myList}'>{{item}}</span>'" 
     popover-trigger="'mouseenter'"
     popover-placement="auto bottom-right">
</div>
```

I don't want to use uib-popover-template. Need to achieve using uib-popover-html.

Comment: If you're unable to use `uib-popover-template` you are probably out of luck unfortunately. `uib-popover-html` never binds $scope variables and doesn't process any directives within the html string, even when the html is trusted via `$sce.trustAsHtml()`. `uib-popover-template` is as far as I can tell the only viable option https://plnkr.co/edit/k3O2VARt3pC8zbZ4Trm6?p=preview